# ActiveMQ Classic is showing slave even though it is a master

Tags: activemq-classic

I am very new to ActiveMQ Classic 5.16.3. I got couple of servers installed using master-slave architecture. When I am trying to run `curl <ip_addreess>:<port_no>` from the server where ActiveMQ server is installed, I am getting `slave` as an output instead of `master`. But when I hit the url in the UI, I am able to view the ActiveMQ web console on screen. (I assume that the server where ActiveMQ is master will only display the page and not the actual slave).

[image]

Although the output of `curl` command in slave is coming as slave only.
I am not getting what is wrong with the setup.

Please find output of `curl` command:

[image]

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram, I am not sure whether it is activemq-classic or not but I am running activemq 5.16.3. Also the curl command which I mentioned in the question is correct, I am getting output as slave only, I have edited the question and posted the output of command there.

Comment: Are you certain that your instance of ActiveMQ Classic is listening for HTTP requests on port `6380`? If so, what makes you certain? The default HTTP port is `8161`.